# Unwanted 1px border when using tables - using bootstrap system

Tags: html, css, formatting, border

I'm developing a new portfolio site (you can see a test here - http://2loot.com/newsite/)

I'm using css to vertically align the next in the chosen grid sections, but it's adding an annoying 1px border and making clear lines appear around the boxes (you can see this in the example above).

I've tried amending the table{} properties, but for some reason I can't resolve it! I've tried collapsible borders, 0 padding, 0 margin, 0 border-spacing.

```
table,
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this, I'm probably missing something quite simple...

Thank you!

A quick edit: What I meant to say is that I'm using: display: table-cell for my .headerText class, and the parent class uiOverlay is using display: table; to align the text vertically.

It's causing an unwanted 1px border in some places (please see the attached - i.imgur.com/IERNS6l.jpg)

Comment: I'm not seeing any borders or tables on your site...

Comment: there is no `<table>` on your page.

Comment: sorry, what I meant to say is that I'm using: display: table-cell for my .headerText class, and the parent uiOverlay is using display: table; to align the text vertically, but it's causing a 1px border (please see the attached - http://i.imgur.com/IERNS6l.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but try to add this to your css to see if it helps:

```
#feature-sec {
  position: relative;
  right: 1px;
  width: 101%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, moving the grid around does work, but it seems like a bit of a hack, for a better idea have a look at this (http://i.imgur.com/iyuNX7g.jpg), it seems that adding display:table sometimes adds a thin 1px border around each section. I'll keep looking for an answer and post it if I find anything out!